# Show CSS in Option of Dropdownlist

Tags: html, css, select, option-type

how can I make the CSS part be displayed on the options in my dropdown list?

Here is a example what i want: codepen.io/luisaof392/pen/wvOjVGE
there you can actually recognize what I want

I'm new to the coding scene and saw on Google that I need to import a stylesheet and a script to display css in a dropdown list

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_custom_select.asp